# definition of qwtplot

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qwt

it's my first post, hope to not break something :).
On windows there are two versions of python2.7, 32 bit and 64 bit both with pyqt and qwt5
i'm trying pyqt from some week, today i tried to use my python/pyqt/pyqwt code written on linux, on windows, but the prompt says:

```
C:\Users\bomba\Desktop\conversione_python\guibms>python-32 interfaccia_mark3.2.p
y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interfaccia_mark3.2.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PyQt4.Qwt5.qplt import *

  File "C:\Python27-32bit\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\Qwt5\qplt.py", line 95, in <mo
dule>

    Y1 = Left   = QwtPlot.yLeft

NameError: name 'QwtPlot' is not defined
```

someone could explain me this?

I would really apppreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the `Qwtplot` object.
Try using:

```
import PyQt4.Qwt5 as Qwt
plot = Qwt.QwtPlot()
```

and then use the `plot` object as you wish.

Comment: thanks for answer, but the same error remains. 

in which module should be defined the qwtplot? there a problem in qplt i think...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late with the paste, but i didn't understand how to solve it

Comment: if i do as you say the prompt prints


C:\Users\bomba\Desktop\conversione_python\guibms>python-32 interfaccia_mark3.2.p
y

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interfaccia_mark3.2.py", line 13, in <module>
    plot = Qwt.QwtPlot(self.scrollAreaWidgetCont_middle)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QwtPlot'

Comment: i tried installing pyqt and compiling qwt5.2 again but now my prompt gently says:

NMAKE : fatal error U1052: impossibile trovare il file              'qwt_version_info.mak'                                              
Stop.                                                               
Impossiblo to find the specified path.                              
Failed to import qwt_version_info.

Comment: i solved installing this set:

    python-2.6.2.msi
    numpy-1.3.0-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe
    PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.5.4-1.exe
PyQwt5.2.0-Python2.6-PyQt4.5.4-NumPy1.3.0-1.exe